# Multiple rust files need to use the same structs and functions

Tags: rust

I have a function file_to_bytes() in lib.rs which I need to call from both lib.rs and runtime.rs (and tests.rs, but it's OK from there).

I also have a file klass_parser.rs that contains a struct OtKlassParser that needs to be used in both lib.rs and runtime.rs.

I can't seem to arrange the mod and use declarations correctly - what's the canonical way to do this, and what section of the documentation covers this case?

Comment: Here you can find [Rust 2018 Module System Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/index.html)

Comment: I read it. Several times. Like so much of Rust's documentation, it's next-to-useless for an experienced programmer. Hence asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as this is not covered in the docs.

There appears to be no easy way to do this directly. Instead, the dependency graph that is described in the question is an indication that actually the project needs more structure and to be composed of multiple crates.

In this case, a workable structure looks something like the following:

- klass_parser.rs should be its own crate
- Majority of lib.rs should move into a new crate (called something like vm)
- runtime.rs should become a third separate crate
- Remainder of lib.rs should move into main.rs
- lib.rs should disappear completely

Comment: it is unlikely that you should be needing so many crates to share code among multiple files. If you update the question to include a [mcve] of the problem, we ought to identify a better solution.